# How do I store a stream of data that is scarcely changing in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, stateful, data-stream

Essentially, I have a Flink DataStream which reads from a Kafka topic which rarely changes.

This topic holds records like
**userConsumerIdentifier**

```
{
"user_id":1,
"consumer_id": 1
}
```

I have another stream consuming from another Kafka topic which processes hundreds of events per hour, with records like

**userEvents**

```
{
"user_id":1
"phone_number": "518-555-5555",
"zip": 11111
}
```

My goal is to essentially union or join the userConsumerIdentifier records with userEvents, so each userEvent may now have a consumer_id in in each stream record.

Where I'm getting confused is that userConsumerIdentifier Kafka topic is pretty static. It rarely has records written into it.

How can I pull in userConsumerIdentifer, *I guess* essentially store it for reference, and map it to my userEvents?

I looked in BroadcastState, but I'm not sure it's what I need specifically, and don't want to waste hours diving into a concept that isn't relevant to my use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I think a temporal join from the SQL/Table API is the best way to approach this sort of streaming enrichment use case. This will join each userEvent with the version of the corresponding userConsumerIdentifier that was in effect at the time of the userEvent. I recently made a short video explaining the ins and outs of this approach: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChiAXgTuzaA

However, an event time temporal join relies on watermarks, and this will be problematic in your case, where one of the topics is mostly idle. Idle sources don't produce watermarks, and without watermarks, the temporal join won't emit any results. Working around this problem is doable, but a bit fiddly. You could, for example, define a watermark strategy for the mostly idle table that always returns the equivalent of Long.MaxValue as the watermark, which will have the effect of always joining with the latest version of the userConsumerIdentifier.

If the individual userConsumerIdentifier records are never updated,  you could just do a regular inner join instead, and you'd only get one result for each userEvent, but this will be expensive because the runtime will store all of user events forever so that updated results can be produced should updates ever arrive (even if you know they won't).

You can implement this from scratch instead, but there are a few things to consider:

- how to handle cases where a userEvent arrives before the corresponding userConsumerIdentifier has been processed
- if the userConsumerIdentifier records can be updated, do you care which version gets used?
- in general, broadcast state should be avoided unless the use case can't be handled with keyed state -- because broadcast state is more expensive: it has to be kept on the heap (rocked isn't an option), and each task will checkpoint its own copy of the broadcast state

For an example showing how to implement a similar use case using the DataStream API and keyed state, see https://github.com/confluentinc/flink-cookbook/tree/master/enrichment-join-with-buffering.

Comment: Maybe if I shape what I'm ultimately trying to accomplish the solution may become easier. It's actually less about unioning the two events/records, more than taking a userId from a userEvent, checking if it's in a userConsumerIdentifier event, and if so, enriching the userEvent with the consumer_id. Maybe it doesn't make a difference

Comment: Another question I have is, in a single job can I change contexts and swap between a using the Table Api and Datastream Api? If possible, does that even make sense here? Mind you, I haven't watched your video yet above. I'll check it out

Comment: I assumed you are doing what you are, in fact, doing.

Comment: Yes, you can mix and match the Table and DataStream APIs to your heart's content. They are interoperable, though it requires an explicit conversion step each time you switch APIs.